# SmartGWT- how to change filter button icon in listGrid?

Tags: java, css, gwt, smartgwt, listgrid

I want to change this filter icon to another one, I have tried this method `setFilterButtonProperties(newButton);`
but it doesn't work.

here the image which I want to change.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
    Button newButton=new Button("");
    newButton.setSize("18px", "18px");
    newButton.setIcon("[SKIN]/RecordEditor/add.png");
    listGrid.setFilterButtonProperties(newButton);
```

**Note:** Change the icon path and size as per your requirement.

Comment: thanks for reply , but this cause an error like this : 
[ERROR] [msp] - 10:34:49.854:MOU2:WARN:Log:Specified ID: isc_Button_0 collides with the ID for an existing object '[Button ID:isc_Button_0]'. The existing object will be destroyed and the ID bound to the new object.

Comment: Its just a warning. You can ignore it because `setFilterButtonProperties()` create one more button internally with the same ID that is auto generated by `SmartClient` itself. It means existing button `newButton` will be destroyed and the ID is bound to new filter icon button. That's the correct behavior because we don't need `newButton` at all. It's used just to pass the properties to filter icon button.

Comment: thanks Braj, but the newButton not working , and the new icon not shown , I verified the path and it right.
I think that is ERROR not warning.

Comment: Look at here `10:34:49.854:MOU2:WARN:Log:Specified ID: isc_Button_0`. Its a Warning. I also got it and its working. Try this one `newButton.setIcon("[SKIN]/RecordEditor/add.png");` and set the size also. I have added the snapshot also.

Comment: thanks again Braj, but unfortunately still not working with me , 
i copied and pasted your code above and I just changed the path of the image.
still not appearing.
NOTE:I'm sure for the path of the icon is correct.I tested it alone.